# Is Azure SQL database based on decade old sql server version?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Not sure if this question will be considered appriate here, but looking at this version history: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server
It seems that Azure SQL database has not been updated since 2014. Is that interpretation correct?

I note that the instance of Azure SQL Database does not know about `RowVersion` data type, which surprised me and led me to look into version history. I know that I can use `timestamp` instead of `RowVersion`, but I am wondering if there are any useful features that have been introduced in the last decade that I will have to forgo because I am using Azure SQL Database instead of SQL Server.

For those who vote to close: I take no offense if the community decides to close, but in defense, had my google query found this question and associated answers instead of the wiki page, I would have been better informed.

Comment: Even the Wikipedia page doesn't say it "has not been updated since 2014"; it says it was _released_ in 2014.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is an excerpt from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-paas-overview?view=azuresql):

*Azure SQL Database is based on the latest stable version of the Microsoft SQL Server database engine. You can use advanced query processing features, such as high-performance in-memory technologies and intelligent query processing. In fact, the newest capabilities of SQL Server are released first to Azure SQL Database, and then to SQL Server itself. You get the newest SQL Server capabilities with no overhead for patching or upgrading, tested across millions of databases.*

As Sean suggested, the @@VERSION output is meaningless in the Azure SQL Database world.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that Azure SQL database has not been updated since 2014. Is that interpretation correct?

No, it's not correct. The "version" number always stays the same for Azure SQL DB, but the internal versions do change.

Example, blog posts from the team: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/azure-sql-news-update-november-2022/ba-p/3675397